# Choosing a title for a given passage

Tags: titles, paragraphs

We are usually given a passage/text, which we have to summarize and give a suitable title.

So I was wondering, there are two ways you can give a title :

One is by picking the main line from the passage for example I read a passage where a person see's something through a microscope, upon which he quickly calls his professor, the professor after looking through the microscope responds "That's your eye" . Which could be a title .

Secondly, a person could read the passage and interpret the whole theme and main idea of the passage, and then give a title according to the theme and main idea.

I think both of these also depend upon what type of passage it is, for example, if its information based then I would go for the second option etc.

So was wondering which one is better to do and why or is it "condition-based" ?

Comment: *That's Your Eye* is catchy for a news or magazine article, and will quickly get you into trouble in school. Teachers don't care if you can find an appealing title that teases the reader into reading the article. They are testing your ability to capture the whole piece and summarize it. Read "What's a boring way to condense this piece?" not what's an entertaining title?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Funnily, I did use the " That's Your Eye " title in college,  my teacher laughed and appreciated the title but she indeed preferred " Uneducated Education System " title over my title. I do think the first title attracts a younger audience rather than an older audience. Also I think there is a weird satisfaction in finding the title of the novel/passage in the novel/passage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In school, the best way to **summarize** a passage when you "have to **summarize** and give a suitable title" to it is to gather the entire idea into a few words. [**Summarize**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/point) **it**: Give a brief statement of the *main points* (Lexico).

*That's Your Eye* is catchy for a news or magazine article, and will quickly get you into trouble in school. Teachers don't care if you can find an appealing title that draws the reader into reading the piece. They are testing your "reading comprehension" and "critical reasoning" to capture the whole sense and compress it.

> Read "What's a boring way to **condense** this piece?"
>
> Not "What's an **entertaining** teaser?"

Breaking rules is a sign of creativity. Pleasing authority is a sign of survival skills.

Tests are not the place for creativity, as there are correct answers — expected answers. If the system did not beat that out of you, keep fighting city hall. Or break some rules when you have that freedom. Not on school assignments.

Dictionary.com starts off synonyms of *summarize* with the big picture:

> compile, encapsulate, epitomize, outline, recap, rehash, sum up, abridge, abstract

Comment: "Thanks",  "+1.000000"